# Displaying HTML in Swing

Tags: java, html, swing

I am working on a project of sorts to load HTML files from a server and display them in swing.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class webloader {
    public static void loadcode(){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("web"+File.separator+web.url+File.separator+"index.html");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("text/html;\\s+charset=([^\\s]+)\\s*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(con.getContentType());
        String charset = m.matches() ? m.group(1) : "ISO-8859-1";
        Reader r = null;
        try {
            r = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), charset);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        while (true) {
          int ch = 0;
        try {
            ch = r.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          if (ch < 0)
            break;
          buf.append((char) ch);
        }
        String str = buf.toString();
        JFrame mainframe = new JFrame(web.url);
        mainframe.setSize(800, 750);
        mainframe.setResizable(false);
        JPanel website = new JPanel();
        JLabel webcontent = new JLabel(str);
        website.add(webcontent);
        mainframe.add(website);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Loading test.com
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
roblem:
        Syntax error on token ""web"", delete this token

        at webloader.loadcode(webloader.java:11)
        at web$1.actionPerformed(web.java:46)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sou
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sou
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sou
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sou
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am quite new to Java, so if I seem to be stupid or not know what I am doing, that's because I am.

Comment: `"Error: Unresolved compilation problem:"`: You're trying to run code that won't compile. **Never** do this. Instead try to compile it first, and then if still confused, show us the *compiler's* error message, not that of the JVM.

Comment: There is no compiler error,

Comment: Even the error from above tells you what's wrong; you're using a variable called web, which is not declared (as far as I can tell).

Comment: JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  Exported with compile warnings: browser/src/updated.java
  Exported with compile warnings: browser/src/Checkupdate.java
  Exported with compile warnings: browser/src/web.java

Comment: Where do you see that, Ben? I don't believe I have a variable "web".

Comment: This line;

            url = new URL("web"+File.separator+web.url+File.separator+"index.html");

There's a "web.url"

Comment: Witch is defined in the 'web' class, it pulls the text from the input box, witch in this case is test.com, then its SUPPOSE to go into web/test.com/index.html

Comment: Please follow standard Java conventions; classes start with a capital. I'll drop your code into Eclipse and see what's what. Even though it is not complete.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I kinda am bad with the proper 'grammer' in coding.

Comment: That "proper grammar" is quite important if you are asking volunteers to help you. We usually appreciate the effort you put in to make it easier to understand your code, especially when you're asking for our effort to help you. It's not too much I don't think for us to ask you to clean this up and make your code comply with standards.

Comment: Ok, I will work on that, my apologies.

Comment: Assuming I have a class called 'web' with a public member (*shiver*) called 'url' of type String; this compiles just fine.

Comment: Indeed, then why is this not loading properly?

Comment: Try executing a full, clean build.

Comment: This is the full build, I don't know what you mean.  Do you want me to post the other parts of my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to access the file wrong.

Correct code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class webloader {
    static JComponent page;
    public static void loadcode(){
        JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
         jep.setEditable(false);   

         try {
           jep.setPage("http://(server):(port)/" + web.url);
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
           jep.setContentType("text/html");
           jep.setText("<html>Could not load webpage</html>");
         } 

         JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
         JFrame f = new JFrame(web.url);
         f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
         f.setSize(512, 342);
         f.show();
    }
}
```