# How to have multiple images and text on a content page?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, foreach

I'm writing a program for a "Ski Area" (I hope that's the English term).

If you know a little bit about skiing, you know there are tracks with different difficulties. Now I want to show all the tracks on my window with a little picture (blue, red, black).

I have an `ArrayList` where all the information resides. I get the information from a database.

```
ArrayList<piste> pisteArrayList = dbz.holePistenAusSkigebietNr(skigebietNr);
```

with a "foreach" I can get the information and make a String:

```
for (piste p : pisteArrayList) {
    String bezeichnung = p.getBezeichnung();
    int laengeInM = p.getLaengeInM();
    String schwierigkeit = dbz.holeSchwierigkeitAusSchwierigkeitNr(p.getSchwierigkeitNr());

    String text = " " + schwierigkeit + ": " + bezeichnung + " (" + laengeInM + " )" + "\n";
```

But now here comes the problem: If I use `JTextArea` I can show the text, but can't show images.

And because I'm a starter I don't know anything else.

Can somebody help?

Comment: I wonder if this is best implemented as a custom-painted panel. Do you have an image of what the user might expect to see? BTW I *think* the correct term for 'Ski Area' is 'Ski Runs' or a 'Ski Slope'. But please don't change anything. It should be clear enough as is (with your added words to explain it), and I'm really not *sure* either.

Comment: `for (piste p : pisteArrayList)` As an aside, my native language is English - so Google pushes results that are predominantly *in* English. When I searched 'Ski Area', the term 'Piste' was within the top three results. It's certainly a word I've heard before. We don't mind stealing words from other languages and adopting them as our own. 

Answer (score 1):

To display images together with text you can use

- `JEditorPane` and some HTML document (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779279/4222206)
- `JTable` with images (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947154/4222206, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23560542/4222206)
- `JList` with custom components (https://alvinalexander.com/java/jlist-image-jlabel-renderer/)
- probably more

You have to make up your mind how exactly the output should look.

Comment: if any of this works: i love you